# Convex hull of finite union of closed sets

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $C_1,\cdots,C_n$ are closed, compact, convex subsets of a locally convex topological vector space, then is $\text{Conv}(C_1 \cup \cdots \cup C_n) = \overline{\text{Conv}(C_1 \cup \cdots \cup C_n)}$, i.e. is it closed? My intuition tells me that it is since $C_i$'s are required to contain its limit points, and I vaguely remember limit points are extreme points (Is it? Please correct me if I am wrong). So the convex hull of the finite union contains all the extreme points of the union and hence it is closed.

Anyway, I was told by a friend that I might be able to prove it by using nets, which I am not very sure how to construct one if that is even possible. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to mention, $C_i$ are subsets of a locally convex topological vector space, so the norm is not really defined here.

Comment: Since the $C_k$ are convex, you have $$\operatorname{Conv}(C_1\cup \dotsc \cup C_n) = s\left(\Delta \times \prod_{k = 1}^n C_k\right)$$ where $\Delta$ is the simplex $\left\{(t_1,\dotsc,t_n) : t_k \geqslant 0,\; \sum_{k = 1}^n t_k = 1\right\}$ and $s(t_1,\dotsc,t_n,x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n t_k\cdot x_k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. In fact, that is an equality I proved before, and I don't really see how that helps. ):

Comment: What properties of $\Delta \times \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n C_k$ would you expect to be relevant here?

Comment: Oh shit, that's compact. Then you can apply Krein-Milman! :O

Comment: What has Krein-Milman to do with it? It's compact, $s$ is continuous, hence $\operatorname{Conv}(C_1 \cup \dotsc \cup C_n)$ is compact [hence closed, if the space is Hausdorff]. No extreme points mentioned.

Comment: I think you can prove $\text{Conv}(\text{Ext}(\text{Conv}(C)) = \text{Conv}(C)$. It wasn't assumed Hausdorffness in my problem so I'll try to avoid using it if possible.

Comment: If you don't assume Hausdorffness, it need not be closed. Simplest example: $n = 1$ and $C_1 = \{0\}$. Not Hausdorff? Not closed.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess that would be implicitly implied within LCTVS definition then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Apply the theorem of Krein-Milman

Comment: How do you know the convex hull of the union itself is compact in that case?

Comment: I the spaces are separated, you can easily show this by considering sequences.

Comment: Okay, I will try both methods and keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to both @Tsemo and @Daniel.

Basically using the fact that Daniel mentioned, $\text{Conv}(C_1 \cup \cdots\cup C_n)$ is compact. Now LCTVS are Hausdorff, so it is a compact subset of a Hausdorff space which is closed.

Otherwise since the convex hull is itself compact, proceed to prove that $\text{Conv}(\text{Ext}(\text{Conv}(C))) = \text{Conv}(C)$, and apply Krein-Milman.

Please upvote Tsemo's answer instead, or Daniel's if he decided to post the solution.